# Como adicionar um array a um atributo value?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, select

Olá! estou com problemas estou usando em um formulario um campo select multiplo com o plugin choseen-select  http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

```
<form id="cadastro" action="process_teste.php" method="post">
<select id="form-edit-selecionar" name="fornecedor[]" data-placeholder="Fabricantes" style="width:330px;" multiple class="chosen-select" tabindex="2">
<?php while($row2Fnc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2Fnc)) :?>
        <option value="<?=$row2Fnc["id"];?>"><?=$row2Fnc["blablabla"];?></option>
<?php endwhile ?>
      </select>
 <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
```

e estou recebendo dados do php via ajax com $getJSON e quero adicionar o id no value do select, tentei isso aqui mas nao deu certo, a variavel options_val tem todos os ids, mas o select esta null!

```
$.getJSON('process_forn.php?valor='+data, function (dados){ 
        var options_val = [];   
            for (var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
            options_val += dados[i].id;
            }           
            $("#form-edit-selecionar").val(options_val);
            alert(options_val)  
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você quer popular um select com opções. Me corrija se eu estiver errado...

Para popular o array:

```
$.getJSON('process_forn.php?valor='+data, function (dados){ 
    var options_val = [];   
        for (var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
            options_val[i] = dados[i].id;
        }           
});
```

Para chamar a primeira opcao (dentro do for):

```
alert(options_val[0]);
```

Para preencher o seu select com as opções (dentro do for):

```
$("#form-edit-selecionar").append("<option value=" + options_val[i] + "> Nome da opção <option>");
```

Como você usa um plugin, talvez você tenha que dar um "refresh" no seu select para que o plugin remonte ele com os novos dados. Geralmente com o js que você ativou ele no inicio do carregamento da página funciona, mas se não funcionar veja na documentação do plugin se há outra forma.